# Hw to prevent Google chrome from loading old javascript after writing a meaningless command in the console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I wrote some code that didn't work so I wanted to try running specific parts of the code to find the wrongs but I accidentally copied all my code and it makes my program act weird now whenever I write anything in the console.

More specifically I'm making a program that draws by placing pictures at mouse pointer but I made it so whenever I write something in the console it makes it so I draw far more than normally.

I have tried reloading the page, closing chrome and opening it again as well as restarting my computer. I have also tried clearing the console with console.clear() but none of my attempts have worked.

Here is the code that I use to draw with:

```
function tegn() {
  if(MusTilstand == 1) { //this is the drawing function
    var x = event.clientX;
    var y = event.clientY;
    var coor = "X coords: " + x + ", Y coords: " + y;
    document.getElementById("demoo").innerHTML = coor;

    pnktArrayX[counter2].push(x);
    pnktArrayY[counter2].push(y);

    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "https://www.astrology-zodiac-signs.com/images/cancer.jpg";
    img.width = 50;
    img.height = 50;
    img.style.zIndex = -1;
    img.alt = "Image";
    img.id = ("idd" + counter);

    document.body.appendChild(img);

    var y = document.getElementById("idd" + counter);
    y.style.position = "absolute";
    y.style.left = (event.pageX - 25 + 'px');
    y.style.top = (event.pageY - 25 + 'px');

    counter = (counter + 1);

  }
}
```

Don't know if its relevant but here is some more of the code for drawing:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDown);
function mouseDown() {
  if(MusTilstand == 0) {
    MusTilstand = 1;
    pnktArrayX.push([]);
    pnktArrayY.push([]);
  } else {
    MusTilstand = 0;
    counter2 = counter2 + 1;
  }
  
}
```

Here are some links to show the difference between drawing the way my code works normally and the way it works after I have written something in the console:

[image: https://imgur.com/a/u1v4nw7]
This image is when I draw normally

[image: o]
This is what happens after I have written a command in the console

Comment: reload the page ... F5 ... nothing is "remembered" between page loads ... or ctrl-F5 to ignore cache

Comment: try to use Ctrl + Shift + R

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl + F5 to reload page while ignoring cache.